# Implementation of Redux Persist with Redux Toolkit. After implementation, can't see todos

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

Today i tried to implement redux persist to save todos in the local storage.
I have made everything right using documentation, but the problem now is that i have todos in the local storage, but can't see todos in the app.
Before implementation, everything works fine. Must understand this part of using locaStorage with redux toolkit/redux-persist.

If someone can show where i have made an error.

Thx a lot!

store.js

```
import {combineReducers, configureStore} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {
    persistStore,
    persistReducer,
    FLUSH,
    REHYDRATE,
    PAUSE,
    PERSIST,
    PURGE,
    REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' // defaults to localStorage for web
import todoReducer from './todoSlice';


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    todoReducer,
});

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)


const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
            serializableCheck: {
                ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
            },
        }),
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
export default store;
```

todoSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = [];

const todoSlice = createSlice({
    name: "todos",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        //Adding todos
        addTodos: (state, action) => {
            state.push(action.payload);
            return state;
        },
        //remove todos
        removeTodos: (state, action) => {
            return state.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload);
        },
        //update todos
        updateTodos: (state, action) => {
            return state.map((todo) => {
                if (todo.id === action.payload.id) {
                    return {
                        ...todo,
                        item: action.payload.item,
                    };
                }
                return todo;
            });
        },
        //completed
        completeTodos: (state, action) => {
            return state.map((todo) => {
                if (todo.id === action.payload) {
                    return {
                        ...todo,
                        completed: !todo.completed,
                    };
                }
                return todo;
            });
        },
    },
});

export const {
    addTodos,
    removeTodos,
    updateTodos,
    completeTodos,
} = todoSlice.actions;

export default todoSlice.reducer;
```

displayTodos.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {
    completeTodos,
    removeTodos,
    updateTodos,
} from "../redux/todoSlice";
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem";
import {AnimatePresence, motion} from "framer-motion";

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        todos: state,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        removeTodo: (id) => dispatch(removeTodos(id)),
        updateTodo: (obj) => dispatch(updateTodos(obj)),
        completeTodo: (id) => dispatch(completeTodos(id)),
    };
};

const DisplayTodos = (props) => {
    const [sort, setSort] = useState("active");
    return (
        <div className="displaytodos">
            <div className="buttons">
                <motion.button
                    whileHover={{scale: 1.1}}
                    whileTap={{scale: 0.9}}
                    onClick={() => setSort("active")}
                >
                    Active
                </motion.button>
                <motion.button
                    whileHover={{scale: 1.1}}
                    whileTap={{scale: 0.9}}
                    onClick={() => setSort("completed")}
                >
                    Completed
                </motion.button>
                <motion.button
                    whileHover={{scale: 1.1}}
                    whileTap={{scale: 0.9}}
                    onClick={() => setSort("all")}
                >
                    All
                </motion.button>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <AnimatePresence>
                    {props.todos.length > 0 && sort === "active"
                        ? props.todos.map((item) => {
                            return (
                                item.completed === false && (
                                    <TodoItem
                                        key={item.id}
                                        item={item}
                                        removeTodo={props.removeTodo}
                                        updateTodo={props.updateTodo}
                                        completeTodo={props.completeTodo}
                                    />
                                )
                            );
                        })
                        : null}
                    {/* for completed items */}
                    {props.todos.length > 0 && sort === "completed"
                        ? props.todos.map((item) => {
                            return (
                                item.completed === true && (
                                    <TodoItem
                                        key={item.id}
                                        item={item}
                                        removeTodo={props.removeTodo}
                                        updateTodo={props.updateTodo}
                                        completeTodo={props.completeTodo}
                                    />
                                )
                            );
                        })
                        : null}
                    {/* for all items */}
                    {props.todos.length > 0 && sort === "all"
                        ? props.todos.map((item) => {
                            return (
                                <TodoItem
                                    key={item.id}
                                    item={item}
                                    removeTodo={props.removeTodo}
                                    updateTodo={props.updateTodo}
                                    completeTodo={props.completeTodo}
                                />
                            );
                        })
                        : null}
                </AnimatePresence>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DisplayTodos);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that your problem is with

```js
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    todoReducer,
});
```

That means that in the end, data from that slice will be available in `state.todoReducer`.

I would assume that before all this, you had

```js
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        todos: todoReducer
    },
})
```

so you would now do

```js
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    todos: todoReducer,
});
```

just the same and your todo slice would stay at `state.todos`

PS: you should really not be using `connect/mapStateToProps/mapDispatchToProps` nowadays. Use `useSelector`/`useDispatch` instead.